# Where does VS get the old assembly reference meta data

Tags: c#, dll, reference, version, .net-assembly

I try to reference a dll library in VS but it keeps giving the message below:
(The assembly trying to be loaded is the older version which i don't reference at all. But it is still saved someplace and it prevents me from referencig a newer dll version)

> Could not load file or assembly '......, Version=......, Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=...........' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's 
>       manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from 
>       HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Where does it get the version#, key token ... etc so that i can change or delete it?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler gets the [AssemblyVersion] from the reference assembly, the one that's in your project's References node.  Clearly at runtime it finds *another* version of that DLL.

Not that many ways to shoot your foot like this, on your dev machine you can be sure to get the same version by setting the reference's Copy Local property to True.  Watch out for a .config file that intentionally tells the CLR to look elsewhere.  If this happens on a test machine then there's something wrong with the way you deploy the project.  If you have no clue where the DLL might come from then use Fuslogvw.exe and log all bindings to get a trace of how the CLR located the DLL.